# My question is to broad, can I improve it like this?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

Original [What makes state's authority over me legal?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/524/what-makes-states-authority-over-me-legal)

Judging by the answers should I change it to **From state's point of view what makes his authority over me legal?**

Answer (score 2):

You are adding clarity to an existing question, and not really straying from the original intent of the question.  I'd say that qualifies as a "Yes, it's a great edit!"

Comment: I'd say that the edit is good because it adds "clarity" FROM THE SITE'S point of view.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, this, and other SE Sites discourages questions that are likely to to solicit "opinions," particularly of a personal nature. A question about "What makes a state's authority over me legal?" falls into this category.

A preferred format is to ask about "practices." A question that begins, "From a state's point of view..." fits the bill. Now, you're not asking for PERSONAL opinions, but rather the practices (or opinions) of an "informed" or "expert" entity such as a state that is "putting its money where its mouth is."

Another acceptable format might be, "What do political philsophers such as Robert Nozick say about..." Now you're asking for EXPERT opinion, which is "in bounds" on the site. This in contrast to, "what is YOUR opinion..." which was implied in the original question.